# Global Function for getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, rest, object

i want a global function in an object for the REST communication. I think this is the right way, but something is wrong. Can someone help?

```
var REST = new Object();
REST.url = "http://xxx/REST/";
REST.GetFromRest = function (request, parameter) {
    var strName, strValue;
    $.getJSON(this.url + request, {
        for(strName in parameter)
        {
            strName: parameter[strName],
        }
    },
    function(responseREST) {
        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(responseREST.data);
        return arr;
    });
}
```

How i send parameters when i never know how much and which parameters maybe send.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Why are you doing this anyway? Surely you're just writing extra code around the already shortened jQuery `$.getJSON`?

Comment: I want one function for all my getJSON requests. So i create an object and call REST.GetFromRest with the parameters and the substring of the REST-URL.

Comment: Why not just `$.getJSON(REST.url, { .... parameters ... }` though? It's already done for you

Comment: Maybe you're right. I thought i have less code with this.